# How to append data based on class name and div id?

Tags: jquery

I am having the following CSS present in a for loop .

This below css is present under for loop , so i am using double quotes for dynamic id generation .

```
<div class="col"><a href="#"  id="'+v_item_id+'" class="btn btn-sm topp ">Topping</a>
<a  href="#" id="'+v_item_id+'" class="btn btn-sm crust">Crust</a>
</div>
<div class="price" >25</div>
<div class="col total total_'+random_number+'" id_attr="'+random_number+'">25</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="Topping-details id=" '+v_item_id+' "></div></div></div>
```

On click of the Topping Link , i am making a AJAX call as shown

```
$(document).on("click", ".topp", function () 
{
 var id_attr_val = $(this).attr("id");
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://hostip:8080/Snacks/oms/toppings?toppingid=' + id_attr_val,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function (response) {
           var toppingres = response;
        var toppingcart = '<img src="images/arrow-topping.png"/><section><i id="topping-close"></i>';
  for (var i = 0; i < toppingres[0].toppings.length; i++){
  toppingcart += '<a href="#">'+toppingres[0].toppings[i]+'</a>';
  }
  toppingcart += '</section>';
   $("div#"+id_attr_val).append(toppingcart);
            },
        });
});
```

When i tried the above way , 
The toppingcart  is not being appended to the div class Topping-details

Incase if use `$('.Topping-details').append(toppingcart)` , the data is being appended to all the elements (since above CSS is present in the for loop)

Is there anyway i can target the div id only ??

Whole CSS

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div class="prd-items-detials">
        <ul>
            <li class="head">
                <form>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclas" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="' + random_number + '" data-mini="true" id_attr="' + random_number + '">
                    <label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">' + responseinner[i].name + '</label>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="prd-items-qt">
                <div class="col"><span class="prd-sm-img"><img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="' + imgsrc + responseinner[i].image + '"/><span></div><div class="col"><i class="minus" id_attr="' + random_number + '"></i><i  class="qt qt_' + random_number + '" id_attr="' + random_number + '">1</i><i class="plus" id_attr="' + random_number + '"></i></div><div class="col"><a href="#" style="display:' + dis_top_val + '" id="' + v_item_id + '" class="btn btn-sm topp ">Topping</a><a id="' + v_item_id + '" href="#" style="display:' + dis_crust_val + '" class="btn btn-sm crust">Crust</a></div><div  class="price" style="display:none;">' + responseinner[i].price + '</div><div class="col total total_' + random_number + '" id_attr="' + random_number + '">' + responseinner[i].price + '</div></li></ul></div><div class="Topping-details" id="' + v_item_id + '"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Have a close look at the last line in your HTML... the syntax highlight helps.

Comment: You should not append to identical Ids.. Look at the difference at http://jsfiddle.net/ZK4kX/

Comment: But i need same id's for different elements as per my functionality

Comment: @PreethiJain Then use 'data-id' or class 'id-yourid' then you can split it up via javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably combine the id and class selector.

```
$("#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details").append(toppingcart);
```

It will find that ID having class `Topping-details`

Answer (score 0):

You should use '.nextAll()'.

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.Topping-details').eq(0).append(toppingcart);
```

What does this do?

$(this) refers to your '.topp' which is in a div with class '.col'.

We get the parent of $(this) which is the div '.col', we search for an element '.Topping-details' which is located after the div.

Comment: Thanks , but still it isn't working . I am pasting whole of my css in my question , could you please help ?

Comment: Did you fixed the markup of '.Topping-details'? class="Topping-details id=" '+v_item_id+' " to class="Topping-details"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55620/discussion-between-preethi-jain-and-newboyhun).

Answer (score 0):

the "CSS" is actually HTML. CSS is different, and being used for styling. Also there are some HTML errors. Please correct these. Like here below;

```
<div class="Topping-details" id=" '+v_item_id+' "></div>
```

Notice the `"` after 'Topping-details'.

And if you want to target a node with a specific id using jQuery, you can use `$('#_id_')`. where the `_id_` is the id of the node of which you want to append `toppingcart`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("div#"+id_attr_val).each(function(index, element){
      $(element).append(toppingcart);
});
```